# Inspect an Exception object like a normal object in Firefox dev tools

Tags: javascript, exception, firefox-developer-tools

I'm trying to debug an issue where I have an exception being thrown and caught. When I log it to the console, Firefox displays it completely differently from a normal object:

[image]

I can force it to display like a normal object by doing `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(e))`, but is there a less clunky way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a breakpoint within the `catch` block, you can see the exception's properties using the *Scopes* panel in the sidebar of the [*Debugger* panel](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger).

In that panel, all objects of the current stack frame are shown under the *Block* scope.

[image: Exception object]

In addition to that, I have now also created an [enhancement request asking to add a way to display an exception's properties within the console](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1624004).

PS: To log errors, you can use [`console.error()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/error) instead of `console.log()`.